# Pyinstaller - How to handle multiple python scripts

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a python script that calls other python scripts using `subprocess.Popen`. These other python scripts are located in different directories.

My end goal is to make the program executable using `pyinstaller`, in an attempt to make the code more secure.

One solution would be to import the other scripts, instead of using subprocess. In this way they would be embedded in the executable file and would thus be protected.
But importing them is not an option.

For this reason, I guess I also have to make the other scripts executable using Pyinstaller and use subprocess to call each executable.

I've read the [Pyinstaller's Multipackage Bundles](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html?highlight=multiprogram#multipackage-bundles)
but I'm not sure if this is what I need.

My question is, how can I call the other python scripts using subprocess (or call their executable) and at the same time protect their source code?

Comment: Where are the additional scripts in releation to your main script? Are they usually in the same directory?

Comment: If they are in the same directory you could get away with adding them to your `datas` within the spec file

Comment: If adding them in `datas` doesn't that mean that the `py` files will be available on the `_MEIxxxxxx-folder` as the program is being executed?

Comment: it will be added to your finished build folder in `dist`, unless you are using --onefile

Comment: Yes, sorry I was talking about the --onefile option. So by adding them on `datas` and use the `--onefile` option, that means the files would be available on the temporary folder that is created at runtime, right?

Comment: This is correct

Comment: Could you not have defined paths for your python files you want to call using subprocess? Or could you not add them to your `datas`, and have them extracted at runtime?

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could create a [chat room](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) so we could discuss further!

Comment: Your rep is too low for chat

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "extracted at runtime". The python files need to be saved somewhere in the bundle or in the temp folder so they can be executed at run time. So I guess the answer would be that they cannot be extracted at runtime.

Comment: So when you build a `--onefile`, it creates an exe that is extracts in your temp directory. That temp directory looks almost exactly the same as if you built without the `--onefile`. Can you not package your scripts into the single exe and then have them extracted in the temp directory? They would then be longside the exe.
Another method could be to keep the scripts you want to run with subprocess in a dedicated folder and call them using the directory within your built script.